# Neo4j Family Tree Relationship Design

Tags: neo4j, relationship, family-tree

I am designing an extended family tree using Neo4j.
During the design of the relationships I came up with two approaches:

1. `CREATE (p:Person)-[:PARENT_OF]->(s:Person)
    CREATE (p:Person)-[:STEPPARENT_OF]->(s:Person) 
    CREATE (p:Person)-[:MARRIED_TO]->(s:Person)`

With this approach I am creating different relationships for every case (keep in mind that there will be a lot of cases = a lot of relationships)

2. `CREATE (p:Person)-[r:PARENT_OF {type:'natural'}]->(s:Person)
    CREATE (p:Person)-[r:PARENT_OF {type:'step'}]->(s:Person)
    CREATE (p:Person)-[r:SPOUSE_OF {type:'marriage'}]->(s:Person)`

With this approach there will be less relationships but the design is a little bit messy.

I would like to know which approach will be better and why?

Comment: what are the questions your data will answer ?

Comment: Some of them might be:
Who are John's parents?
Who is John related to?
Who are John's children?
Is John divorced?
Does John have adopted child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are choosing beetwen fine-grained (`:PARENT_OF`, `:STEPPARENT_OF`, `:MARRIED_TO`) or generic relationships (`:PARENT_OF {type:'natural'}`, `:PARENT_OF {type:'step'}`, `:SPOUSE_OF {type:'marriage'}`).

The book Graph Databases (available for [download](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/) in the Neo4j site) by By Ian Robinson, Jim Webber, and Emil Eifrém says:

> Differentiating by relationship name is the best way of eliminating
>   large swathes of the graph from a traversal. Using one or more
>   property values to decide whether or not to follow a relationship
>   incurs extra I/O the first time those properties are accessed because
>   the properties reside in a separate store file from the
>   relationships (after that, however, they’re cached).

Remember that a graph database model should be built focused on the application needs. That is: it depends basically on what type of queries are you asking to your database.

- If you need to evaluate the `type` of the relationship in your graph transversal queries, probably is a good idea split it into separated relationship types.
- Otherwise, keep it as a property of a generic relationship type.